# Integration & bremsstrahlung calculation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, photon-emission

In this [paper](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.122.1898) ([relevant pdf section](http://www.filedropper.com/radiativecorrectionstoelectron-protonscattering-tsai1961)) that I'm reading, involving the calculation of bremsstrahlung in electron proton scattering (diagram below), the author calculates the integral over outgoing photons and scattered electron:
$$\tag{III.10} A=\int d\Omega\int_{E_\text{3,min}}^{E_\text{3,max}}p_3 dE_3 \frac{\sqrt{(kt)^2-\lambda^2t^2}}{2t^2} \theta(E_4) \int {d\tilde\Omega_k} \chi^2$$

The integral is  transformed from an integral over $E_3$ to one over $x\equiv t^2-M^2$, which leads to (up to order $\lambda^2$):

$$A=\int d\Omega\int_{x_\text{min}}^{x_\text{max}}\color{blue} {\frac{p_3}{4M \eta}}\cdot \frac{x dx}{2(x+M^2)} \int {d\tilde\Omega_k} \chi^2$$

**Instead**, the author somehow pulls $p_3$ outside of the integral, and gets:
$$\tag{III.13} A=\int d\Omega \color{blue}{\frac{E_3}{4M \eta}}\int_{x_\text{min}}^{x_\text{max}} \frac{x dx}{2(x+M^2)} \int {d\tilde\Omega_k} \chi^2$$

The author then proceeds to use this expression to compare to the famous Rosenbluth formula, and now the "problem" $E_3$ disappears entirely:

$$\tag{III.18}\left(\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}\right)_\text{brem}=-\left(\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}\right)_\text{Rosenbluth} \times \frac{\alpha}{8\pi^2}\int_{x_\text{min}}^{x_\text{max}} \frac{x dx}{2(x+M^2)} \int {d\tilde\Omega_k} \chi^2$$

### My Questions:

1. What justifies the pulling out of $E_3$ from the integration, when $x$ is clearly a function of $E_3$?
2. Where did the factor $E_3/M\eta$ in $\text{III.13}$ disappear to when comparing the cross sections?

I suspect the answers to these two questions are related, but I can't seem to see how this can be correct.

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

Comment: Hmm - yes I agree his reasoning looks very dodgy. Hopefully it's just a series of typos. Can you tell me what $\eta$ is? I can't find an appropriate definition in a quick scan of those paragraphs!

Comment: @EdwardHughes - $\eta$ is $1+E_1 M^{-1}(1-\cos\theta)$ as defined on the top of the first page. Thanks!

Comment: Also, $\eta=E1/E3$.

Comment: The key comes from understanding how their Lorentz frame choices work. I haven't quite got the hang of it yet, but I'll have another go tomorrow. I think that once you've worked out how to get from III.8 to III.10 the same process reversed will get you from III.10 to III.13.

Comment: @EdwardHughes - any leads?

Comment: I still can't quite make sense of it. Do you know of any other papers which employ a similar method? It's not really my area (I'm more theoretical) so I think I'd need to read around a bit more before understanding it fully!